# How to run code on shutdown or when user enters wrong passcode in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios11

I tried looking for this for some time with no luck yet, I'm trying to build a security app where I need to know when the phone is going to shutdown or the user enters the wrong passcode at the lock screen.

I know apps like Prey, and older apps like iGotYa, would snap a picture using the front facing camera when the user enters the wrong pass on the lock screen. I was looking to do something similar with my app, is this something that requires special access from apple? or is this available to everyday developer? If thats the case, how would approach this problem or where could I find this information?

Thank you in advanced!!!

Comment: Bro , what you want is really needs a special access from apple , only your app can listen for appDelegate callbacks and executes some code in background , I remember one time i listened for lock screen on/off and my app got rejected by Apple in the processing phase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to security reasons Apple doesn't give this level of access to the device. Apple limits the APIs and features applications can take advantage of to protect users and keep devices secure.

There might be a way to do this using some form of jailbreak but nothing that Apple would support officially.

**Edit** great additional point made in the comments. Every app is forced to operate in its own "sandbox", so it can only access things within that applications domain. There are certain cases which applications are allowed to interact with the OS itself through extensions. But these are very limited and highly controlled by Apple.

Comment: What Charlie said. Broadly, Apple does not allow apps to have access to things the user does outside of that app's domain. Every app is forced to operate in its own "sandbox"

Comment: @DuncanC Great addition. One more note, there are limited cases where apps can interact with the OS itself through extensions. Tho these are heavily controlled and designed with security and privacy in mind. Apple basically must add support for any interaction with the OS itself, which they have started to do more of recently.